# Website as a referral

Tags: google-analytics

I have added my website to the referral exclusion list, but it's still coming through as a referral traffic.

Could anyone shed any light as to why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure that people whose visits are already attributed to that self-referral will show up as referrals until they click another campaign link; if tha is your problem it should phase out over time. Not sure if this on-topic, though, since it is not a problem solvable via code.